# Finding the unique values of a column and creating a data frame with length of Unique values in the of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to take a list which has unique values of a column and for every unique value i'm trying to put it in a new data frame by iterating the number of elements in that list

Here in the below code

```
rslt_df1.head()
```

[image: Data Frame]

Below is the list of product sales district codes

```
salesdistcode = rslt_df1['ProdSalesDist'].unique().tolist()
salesdistcode
```

Output:

> ```
> ['03401044CA_0000',
>  '03401044CA_1015',
>  '03401044CA_1047',
>  '03401044CA_1216',
>  '03401044CA_2062',
>  '03401044CA_2065',
>  '03401044CA_2365',
>  '03401048CA_1015',
>  '03401048CA_1019',
>  '03401048CA_1099',
>  '03401048CA_1213',
>  '03401048CA_1216',
>  '03401048CA_1259',
>  '03401048CA_1274',
>  '03401048CA_1289',
>  '03401048CA_1602',
>  '03401048CA_1603',
>  '03401048CA_2002',
>  '03401048CA_2059',
>  '03401048CA_2062',
>  '03401048CA_2065',
>  '03401048CA_2137',
>  '03401048CA_2224',
>  '03401048CA_2260',
>  '03401048CA_2263',
>  '03401048CA_2337',
>  '03401048CA_2365',
>  '03401048CA_2378',
>  '03401048CA_3993',
>  '06442106CA_1015',
>  '06442106CA_1019',
>  '06442106CA_1038',
>  '06442106CA_1099',
>  '06442106CA_1213',
>  '06442106CA_1216',
>  '06442106CA_1259',
>  '06442106CA_1274',
>  '06442106CA_1602',
>  '06442106CA_1948',
>  '06442106CA_2059',
>  '06442106CA_2062',
>  '06442106CA_2065',
>  '06442106CA_2137',
>  '06442106CA_2153',
>  '06442106CA_2168',
>  '06442106CA_2263',
>  '06442106CA_2279',
>  '06442106CA_2303',
>  '06442106CA_2337',
>  '06442106CA_2340',
>  '06442106CA_2354',
>  '06442106CA_2358',
>  '06442106CA_2378',
>  '06442106CA_2406',
>  '06460003AO_1015',
>  '06460003AO_2062',
>  '06460003CA_1015',
>  '06460003CA_1034',
>  '06460003CA_1099',
>  '06460003CA_1274',
>  '06460003CA_2062',
>  '06460003CA_2137',
>  '06460003CA_2220',
>  '06460003CA_3997',
>  '06810107CA_1034',
>  '06810107CA_1038',
>  '06810107CA_1213',
>  '06810107CA_1216',
>  '06810107CA_1235',
>  '06810107CA_1289',
>  '06810107CA_1297',
>  '06810107CA_1326',
>  '06810107CA_1602',
>  '06810107CA_1820',
>  '06810107CA_1872',
>  '06810107CA_2059',
>  '06810107CA_2065',
>  '06810107CA_2137',
>  '06810107CA_2153',
>  '06810107CA_2171',
>  '06810107CA_2174',
>  '06810107CA_2183',
>  '06810107CA_2188',
>  '06810107CA_2227',
>  '06810107CA_2241',
>  '06810107CA_2244',
>  '06810107CA_2278',
>  '06810107CA_2280',
>  '06810107CA_2291',
>  '06810107CA_2304',
>  '06810107CA_2352',
>  '06810107CA_2353',
>  '06810107CA_2378',
>  '06810107CA_2389',
>  '06810107CA_2406',
>  '06810112CA_1326',
>  '06810112CA_2224']
> ```

Our next code:

```
dict_df = {}

#df_1 = pd.DataFrame()

for prod_id in salesdistcode:
    saleDist_code_df = dfpsd[dfpsd['ProdSalesDist'] == prod_id]
    dict_df[prod_id] = saleDist_code_df
    #print(type(prod_id))
```

I'm creating a data frame manually as below

```
df_03401044CA_0000 = pd.DataFrame(dict_df['03401044CA_0000'])
df_03401044CA_1015 = pd.DataFrame(dict_df['03401044CA_1015'])
df_03401044CA_1047 = pd.DataFrame(dict_df['03401044CA_1047'])
df_03401044CA_1216 = pd.DataFrame(dict_df['03401044CA_1216'])
```

But I want the above data frame to be created using a loop , I need help on that

Below is the result i'm expecting , creating a data frame automatically using the naming convention from the list

```
df_03401044CA_0000
df_03401044CA_1015
df_03401044CA_1047
df_03401044CA_1216
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are asking.  So I give it a try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(fn)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | Invoice | Date | ProdSalesDist | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | A | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | B | 55 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | C | 10 |
| 3 | 4 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | A | 30 |
| 4 | 5 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | C | 28 |
| 5 | 6 | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | A | 73 |
| 6 | 7 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | B | 16 |
| 7 | 8 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 | C | 54 |
| 8 | 9 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | B | 33 |
| 9 | 10 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | D | 37 |
| 10 | 11 | 2021-12-25 00:00:00 | E | 44 |
| 11 | 12 | 2021-12-26 00:00:00 | F | 77 |
| 12 | 13 | 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | A | 13 |
| 13 | 14 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | B | 23 |
| 14 | 15 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | F | 25 |
| 15 | 16 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | E | 70 |
| 16 | 17 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | D | 10 |
| 17 | 18 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | C | 6 |
| 18 | 19 | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | C | 64 |
| 19 | 20 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | A | 36 |
| 20 | 21 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 | B | 17 |
| 21 | 22 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | C | 94 |
| 22 | 23 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | B | 100 |

```
unique = pd.factorize(df.ProdSalesDist)[1]
for i,v in enumerate(unique):
    globals()['rslt_df_' + f'{i:04d}'] = df[df.ProdSalesDist == v]
```

Output:

```
print(rslt_df_0000.to_markdown())
```

|  | Invoice | Date | ProdSalesDist | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | A | 15 |
| 3 | 4 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | A | 30 |
| 5 | 6 | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | A | 73 |
| 12 | 13 | 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | A | 13 |
| 19 | 20 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | A | 36 |

```
print(rslt_df_0005.to_markdown())
```

|  | Invoice | Date | ProdSalesDist | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 12 | 2021-12-26 00:00:00 | F | 77 |
| 14 | 15 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | F | 25 |

Comment: Thanks but let me rephrase my question for better understanding

Comment: Please read the 2nd answer.  I'll delete this later.

Answer (score 0):

As you've changed the question, I'll post another answer to the latest update to your question.

I analyse your questions.  I understand your issue is:

1. you want a Dictionary of DataFrames.
2. you want the DataFrame name to have the convention df_xxxxx where xxxxx is the entry in the ProdSalesDist. But you don't know how to create this DataFrame name.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pprint import pprint
df = pd.read_excel(fn)
print(df.to_markdown())
```

|  | Invoice | Date | ProdSalesDist | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 15 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 55 |
| 2 | 3 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1047 | 10 |
| 3 | 4 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 30 |
| 4 | 5 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 28 |
| 5 | 6 | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 73 |
| 6 | 7 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1047 | 16 |
| 7 | 8 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 54 |
| 8 | 9 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 33 |
| 9 | 10 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 37 |
| 10 | 11 | 2021-12-25 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1047 | 44 |
| 11 | 12 | 2021-12-26 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 77 |
| 12 | 13 | 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 13 |
| 13 | 14 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 23 |
| 14 | 15 | 2022-01-29 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1047 | 25 |
| 15 | 16 | 2022-01-30 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 70 |
| 16 | 17 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 10 |
| 17 | 18 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 6 |
| 18 | 19 | 2022-01-22 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 64 |
| 19 | 20 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 36 |
| 20 | 21 | 2022-01-13 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1015 | 17 |
| 21 | 22 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1047 | 94 |
| 22 | 23 | 2022-01-04 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_1216 | 100 |

```
dict_df = {}

unique = pd.factorize(df.ProdSalesDist)[1]

for i,v in enumerate(unique):
    dict_df[f'df_{v}'] = pd.DataFrame(df[df.ProdSalesDist == v])
```

Dic Output:

```
{'df_03401044CA_0000':     Invoice       Date    ProdSalesDist  Quantity
0         1 2022-01-28  03401044CA_0000        15
4         5 2022-01-21  03401044CA_0000        28
8         9 2022-01-03  03401044CA_0000        33
12       13 2021-12-16  03401044CA_0000        13
16       17 2022-01-31  03401044CA_0000        10
19       20 2022-01-12  03401044CA_0000        36,
 'df_03401044CA_1015':     Invoice       Date    ProdSalesDist  Quantity
1         2 2022-01-29  03401044CA_1015        55
5         6 2022-01-22  03401044CA_1015        73
9        10 2022-01-04  03401044CA_1015        37
13       14 2022-01-28  03401044CA_1015        23
17       18 2022-01-21  03401044CA_1015         6
20       21 2022-01-13  03401044CA_1015        17,
 'df_03401044CA_1047':     Invoice       Date    ProdSalesDist  Quantity
2         3 2022-01-30  03401044CA_1047        10
6         7 2022-01-12  03401044CA_1047        16
10       11 2021-12-25  03401044CA_1047        44
14       15 2022-01-29  03401044CA_1047        25
21       22 2022-01-03  03401044CA_1047        94,
 'df_03401044CA_1216':     Invoice       Date    ProdSalesDist  Quantity
3         4 2022-01-31  03401044CA_1216        30
7         8 2022-01-13  03401044CA_1216        54
11       12 2021-12-26  03401044CA_1216        77
15       16 2022-01-30  03401044CA_1216        70
18       19 2022-01-22  03401044CA_1216        64
22       23 2022-01-04  03401044CA_1216       100}
```

DataFrame output:

```
print(dict_df['df_03401044CA_0000'].to_markdown())
```

|  | Invoice | Date | ProdSalesDist | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2022-01-28 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 15 |
| 4 | 5 | 2022-01-21 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 28 |
| 8 | 9 | 2022-01-03 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 33 |
| 12 | 13 | 2021-12-16 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 13 |
| 16 | 17 | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 10 |
| 19 | 20 | 2022-01-12 00:00:00 | 03401044CA_0000 | 36 |